# error: bad operand types for binary operator '>=' "else if (bmi <=18.5 >=25.0)"

Tags: java

error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='       "else if (bmi <=18.5 >=25.0)"
how to solve this?

```
    int bmi;
    
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Measure your height and weight.")
    Systen.out.print("Then Calculate your BMI.")
    System.out,print("Enter how many score you got : ")
    bmi = console.nextINt();
    
    if (bmi <= 18.4)
    {
        System.out.println("You're under weight, you need to gain more weight!");
    }
    else if (bmi <=18.5 >=24.9)
    {
        System.out.println("You're normal, Congrats!");
    }
    else if (bmi <=25.0)
    {
        System.out.println("You're Overweight, you need to lose some weight.");
    }
```

Comment: `if (bmi <=18.5 >=24.9)` is similar to `if ((bmi <=18.5) >=24.9)`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Java is not a Python, it doesn't have syntax like `min < value < max`. In Java you need to use logical operators to sum or intersect ranges like `(min < value) && (value < max)` - you can skip parenthesis here.

Comment: still shows bad operand types for binary operator '>=' I also tried putting && in the middle and it showed illegal start of expression

Comment: should be like this `if (bmi <=18.5 && bmi >=24.9)`

Comment: also your conditions are wrong, 2nd-if : `if (bmi >=18.5 && bmi <=24.9)`, 3rd-if `if (bmi >=25.0)`

Comment: when I add && it says illegal start of expression

Comment: @BravoSix can you write that whole expression in the comment

Comment: else if (bmi <=18.5 && >=24.9) and if (bmi >=18.5 && bmi <=24.9) both says illegal start of expression

Answer (score 1):

is it same as this and still showing error?
Also, why take `bmi` as `int`, why not `float` as you are comparing it with float values.
replace `console.nextInt()` to `console.nextFloat()` for accepting float input

```
float bmi = console.nextFloat();
if (bmi <= 18.4)
{
    System.out.println("You're under weight, you need to gain more weight!");
}
else if (bmi >=18.5 && bmi <=24.9)
{
    System.out.println("You're normal, Congrats!");
}
else if (bmi >=25.0)
{
    System.out.println("You're Overweight, you need to lose some weight.");
}
```

Comment: @BravoSix what was the error? what did you write?

Comment: changed (bmi <=18.5 && >=24.9) to (bmi >=18.5 && bmi <=24.9)

Comment: I changed int to float but still does not show result when have decimal point

Comment: instead of `console.nextInt()` use `console.nextFloat()`

Comment: Thanks! it works now sorry just a student and our teacher does not answer questions on chat only on meetings.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int bmi;

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Measure your height and weight.")
Systen.out.print("Then Calculate your BMI.")
System.out,print("Enter how many score you got : ")
bmi = console.nextINt();

if (bmi <= 18.4)
{
    System.out.println("You're under weight, you need to gain more weight!");
}
else if (bmi < 25)
{
    System.out.println("You're normal, Congrats!");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("You're Overweight, you need to lose some weight.");
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what you changed, and why.